# GitLab-CI and CD with .NET

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cd

I've been trying to wrap my head around how it would be possible to implement Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery with GitLab CI for .NET web-applications such as ASP.MVC as well as WEB API2 etc.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to jumpstart into this issue and will be therefore very thankful for advices or maybe samples.

Comment: I would start here: https://medium.com/@gabriel.faraday.barros/gitlab-ci-cd-with-net-framework-39220808b18f

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a question, but if you want advice on where to start with gitlab CI/CD and .net...

- install gitlab runner on the appropriate server
- setup a gitlab-ci.yml in the root of your repository
- use gitlab's Lint to check your .yml to avoid some headaches on syntax
- make sure you register your runner with your Gitlab instance
- configure your .yml to either use or call cmd commands (or scripts)
  https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/
- setup some 'environments if you think they'd work for you
  https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html

  here is a sample .net .yml I made
  [GitLab CI. Path in yml for different users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716124/gitlab-ci-path-in-yml-for-different-users/44375430#44375430)